# disable event receiver in sharepoint list

Tags: list, development, event-receivers

Can anyone tell me that how can i disable an event receiver on one SharePoint list while adding an item in other?

For example i want to disable event receiver on list B while i add item in list A.

I have event receiver registered on both the list. What happens is when i add item in List A the event receiver for this list gets triggered and adds item in List B but on the same time the event receiver on List B gets triggered and adds item in list A,this creates an infinite loop.

i want to break this loop such that when an item is added in list A it disables the event receiver on list B and stops the loop.

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Event Receiver set [`SPEventReceiverBase.EventFiringEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.eventfiringenabled.aspx) to false while performing actions which should not trigger other Event Receivers

Answer (score 1):

You can place code something like as below:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        bool allowed = true;

        if (properties.ListTitle == "List A")
        {
           allowed = checkItem(properties);
           // Place your code for item adding for list A
        }

        if (!allowed)
        {
           // Your code when List is different.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        properties.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This is the example for `ItemAdding` event, you can place this code same way in `ItemAdded` event also. Refer this example for more: [Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](https://seminda.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/creating-sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Hope this helps!